# How to get bool value from model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, boolean

I need to create a Javascript validation that will compare values from text-boxes against values in the model.

```
($("#Description").val() != "<%= Model.Description %>")
```

Description is a string in the model, and code above works fine for it.

```
($("#Weight").val() != <%= Model.Weight %>)
```

Weight is a int , and works fine.

And finally if I try to check the bool value it doesn't work at all. Any ideas?

```
($("#PackingFlag").is(':checked') != "<%= Model.PackingFlag %>")
```

Comment: Did you try:$( elem ).prop( "checked" )

Comment: Keep in mind that you're relying on type coercion in your compares. `$("#Weight").val() != <%= Model.Weight %>` might do something strange for some exceptional values. Change it to: `$("#Weight").val() !== ("" + <%= Model.Weight %>)` or something similar to enforce a string compare.

Comment: What happens when you do `$("#PackingFlag").is(':checked') != <%= Model.PackingFlag.ToString().ToLower() %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#PackingFlag").is(':checked')
```

returns a bool.

```
"<%= Model.PackingFlag %>"
```

is a string (hence the `"`)

`bool != string` always returns true.

---

if `Model.PackingFlag` returns the string `true` or `false` then removing the `"` should result in the correct comparision:

```
($("#PackingFlag").is(':checked') != <%= Model.PackingFlag %>)
```

---

client side this results in:

```
 ($("#PackingFlag").is(':checked') != true)
```

Or

```
 ($("#PackingFlag").is(':checked') != false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since right hand side of the comparison is a string, you could try converting the left hand side to a string.

```
(String($("#PackingFlag").is(':checked')) != "<%= Model.PackingFlag %>")
```